# What legitimate reason would an IT Admin have for requesting a user's password to setup a new laptop with Windows 10?

Tags: windows

The IT admin person where I work is currently setting up a new laptop for me and they've asked for my user password so they can finish the job. I'm obviously uncomfortable with that.

I suspect not, but is there any reasonable reason to need this information from me? And if not, is there a plausible reason why an inexperienced admin might prefer to just log in as me?

Comment: Configuring your user profile. Setting up your email client. Installing your printers. Installing your applications. Verifying that you have access to the resources you need. Saving you from having to do all of that yourself. I can think of many reasons why the MIGHT ask you for your password.

Comment: Can't any of that be done without my password? That seems like a massive security risk.

Comment: Well... not entirely. In order to configure your user profile they need to log on as you... with your password. In most cases it's easier to perform these steps while logged on as the user rather than have the user perform them themselves while IT guides them through the process. Tools like Autopilot and Intune can make some of this more "zero touch", but it sounds like your team isn't using those kinds of tools, or at least not fully.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error some IT do by lacking to explain why.

If the request is authentic, an actual laptop change.

Technically speaking he could just change your password and give it to you when the job is done.

In COVID Time if working from home it might break your VPN ressource if the IT change it.

The best way of action is to change it yourself and give a temporary password to them.

He possibly want to setup all your app and copy back your data under your own username.

If working from home, that will allow your profile to be cached too before he ship the laptop

Comment: Thanks yagmoth. I'm 100% convinced that the person in question isn't up to something. It just seems unlikely to me that he can't complete his work without my password - but this isn't my domain, hence the question.

Comment: @JoeH He need to log to copy from data if you want all your data copied over (desktop data, favorite, etc), but like I told he can do it by resetting your password or with you around. If you are able to copy your data you can state it to him too. Some application do it without user intervention, but many enterprise don’t have such as it has cost related to that, its why the manual step

Comment: He won't be copying any data. I'll just be getting a standard issue laptop and the only data from the old one will be from dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

The real reason behind the request is lack of knowledge and professionalism. There is no excuse to do it like that, but it is often an easier way for IT support than doing things correctly. They honestly don't understand that they are compromising their own security by asking users for passwords.

If users should be taught one thing about security, it is: IT support should NEVER ask for your password.

Comment: Thank you Jevgenij. This confirms my suspicions. I'm really not sure what it is he needs my password for.

Comment: @Joe H you have a legitimate concern. Why don't you ask them why they need your password and have them explain it to you? We can only give you possible reasons why they might ask you for your password, but we can't tell you the specific reasons they're asking you for it.